# Can we add multiple listviews in a single layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have Three list to display.How to add them on single layout?
my layout file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

I am using CustomAdapter for each list

```
 mylistview1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    mylistview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    mylistview3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3);
    //1
    CustomAdapterA adapterA = new CustomAdapterA(this, rowItems1);
    mylistview1.setAdapter(adapterA);
    mylistview1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            String member_name = rowItems1.get(position).getMember_name();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + member_name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //2
    CustomAdapterM adapterM = new CustomAdapterM(this, rowItems2);
    mylistview2.setAdapter(adapterM);
    mylistview2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            String member_name = rowItems2.get(position).getMember_name();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + member_name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    //3
    CustomAdapterS adapterS = new CustomAdapterS(this, rowItems3);
    mylistview3.setAdapter(adapterS);
    mylistview3.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            String member_name = rowItems3.get(position).getMember_name();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + member_name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I tried with putting each layout in separate Linear Layout but didnot worked,
can anyone suggest what should be done here???

Answer (score 0):

Try making making each of the ListViews take up exactly 1/3 of the screens height and see if they're visible then.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1
 />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1
 />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially a listview looks like it occupies the whole screen. You have to set their widths accordingly to see them in one screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is to finish one list the next one will be visible the answer is:

No, you cannot do that. On your adapter you should Override `getViewTypeCount()` and return 3 and then generate the correct view for each position.

If you're idea is to have each list occupying 1/3 of the screen you must use the `layout_weight` parameter in your XML like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
 />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
 />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
 />
```

Comment: yes my idea is to place listview one below each,So what you are saying that i should make only one CustomAdapter and check for the ViewCount then accordingly generate the views???

Comment: Yes. You can even make you CustomAdapter that will wrap the other 3. so for example on the getCount() you `return adapter1.getCount() + adpater2.getCount() + adapter3.getCount()`. That's because ListView height are `infinite`, it's a bit impossible for the platform to put one after the other.